# Save row data to different workbook with realtive path (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

could you help me to find mistake? I need to send some values by button to different workbook and save and close (relative path)

```
Sub test()
Dim radek As Integer
Dim radeklist As Integer
Dim seznam As Workbook

For radek = 47 To 47
Set seznam = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "SEZNAM_VYDANYCH_DOKUMENTU.xlsm")
radeklist = seznam.Sheets("SEZNAM_VYDANYCH_DOKUMENTU").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

seznam.Sheets("SEZNAM_VYDANYCH_DOKUMENTU").Range("A" & radeklist & ":G" & radeklist).Value = .Range("B" & radek & ":H" & radek).Value
seznam.Save '<~ save and close the target workbook
seznam.Close savechanges:=False
Next radek
End Sub
```

Comment: `For radek = 47 To 47` makes it do only once. Check that line. Maybe it should be `For radek = 1 To 47`

Comment: Its ok. I need only one row. But this code does not insert any data inside workbook.

Comment: Ok, then try adding `seznam.` before `Sheets("SEZNAM_VYDANYCH_DOKUMENTU").Range("A" `

Comment: **seznam.** `Sheets("SEZNAM_VYDANYCH_DOKUMENTU").Range(....`

Comment: Still not working. Document is opened and closed, but no values here.

Comment: Add `ThisWorkbook` and the sheetname before `Range("B" & radek & ":H" & radek).Value` so it reads: `sezname.Sheets("SEZNAM_VYDANYCH_DOKUMENTU").Range("A" & radeklist & ":G" & radeklist).Value = Thisworkbook.Sheets("SheetName").Range("B" & radek & ":H" & radek).Value`

Comment: try `=ThisWorkbook.SomeWorksheet.Range("B" & radek & ":H" & radek).Value`. And please define radek as Integer, not as Byte. And verify that your source range actually has values and is not empty.

Comment: @Jordan Thank you. That was that mistake. It is working now.

Comment: Editing your question to remove the problem and replace it with working code makes it kind of useless as a question: it's much better to post your own answer instead.

Comment: @TimWilliams ok thx for info. I am new here... :)

Comment: Thanks for the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code

```
Sub test()
Dim radek As Integer
Dim radeklist As Integer
Dim seznam As Workbook

For radek = 47 To 47
Set seznam = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "SEZNAM_VYDANYCH_DOKUMENTU.xlsm")
radeklist = seznam.Sheets("SEZNAM_VYDANYCH_DOKUMENTU").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

seznam.Sheets("SEZNAM_VYDANYCH_DOKUMENTU").Range("A" & radeklist & ":G" & radeklist).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PREHLED").Range("B" & radek & ":H" & radek).Value
seznam.Save '<~ save and close the target workbook
seznam.Close savechanges:=False
Next radek
End Sub
```